# MS Word - Set text as image caption

Tags: vba, ms-word, caption

i have a document with several images.

Under every image i have added via VBA a caption like "Fig.XX "
Under this caption i have a phrase which should be the caption description of this image.

My question is now how do i get the text under the caption into the Placeholder?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTtFf.png)

Comment: Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66901374/edit) your question accordingly. Adding a screenshot of the document might help in understanding what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Posting your code will also help. We need to se what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<<Placeholder>>^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .Style = wdStyleCaption
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Style = wdStyleCaption
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```